# react + jest - mocking a subcomponent in the test clause does not mock the component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, components, react-testing-library

i did a test on jest just to get started with testing react componentsץ

it took me a while to understand that for some reason, my `jest.mock` function aren't affecting the subcomponent

so i did a quick test:

i've create component b.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export default function B({testProp: string}) {
  return (
    <div className="B">
      not printed
    </div>
  );
}
```

and component a that calls it

```
import React from "react";
import B from "./b";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <B testProp="mocking"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then i've created a test class for a that mocks b

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './a';


describe('render', () => {
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('./b', () => ({ testProp }) => <div>A mock with '{testProp}' passed!</div>);
    
  })

  it('renders', () => {
    const { container } = render(<App/>);
    expect(container.textContent)
      .toMatch(`A mock with 'mocking' passed!`);
  });

})
```

but it failed

so i've moved the mock to outside the describe function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './a';

  jest.mock('./b', () => ({ testProp }) => <div>A mock with '{testProp}' passed!</div>);

describe('render', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const { container } = render(<App/>);
    expect(container.textContent)
      .toMatch(`A mock with 'mocking' passed!`);
  });
})
```

and now it passedץ

i couldn't find the docs of jest or react testing-library information about why it failed, and all the examples i see in other questions just assume that without explaining.

do you know what cause this behavior?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, it helped me understand the "hoisted" part, thank you!